# How to define input_dim for Keras recurrent layers properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train some NN to predict timeseries. I am using `Sequentional` model to define my NN structure. It looks like:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, SimpleRNN, Embedding
from keras import optimizers
from keras import losses
model = Sequential()
#model.add(Dense(units=5, input_dim=3, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(SimpleRNN(units=5, input_dim = 3, activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(units=16, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
prop = optimizers.rmsprop(lr=0.01)
sgd = optimizers.sgd(lr=0.01, nesterov=True, momentum=0.005)
model.compile(optimizer=prop, loss='mean_squared_error')
```

It does not execute and returned error is:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected simple_rnn_9_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (221079, 3)
```

When I use commented out `Dense` layer everything is just fine. I read Keras documentation and I see they are using `Embedding` layer. Although, I do not really understand why `Embedding` layer is necessary to use recurrent layers like `SimpleRNN` or `LSTM`.

`train_set` is 2D array with 4 columns - 4-th one is target column, rest are inputs.

Is there any simple way how to use Keras' recurrent layers together with traditional `Dense` layers? I would appreciate explanation and some code examples.

Best regards,
Maks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no expert on this, but this may help

```
import numpy as  np
import numpy as  np

data = np.zeros((10,4))
X = data[:,0:3].reshape(-1,1,3)
y = data[:,3].reshape(-1,1)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

prints:

```
(10, 1, 3)
(10, 1)
```

then:

```
model.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Could you provide some explanation why input needs to be reshaped into 3 dimensional array?

Comment: I cant give you a good explanation. (I don't know enough). See for example https://www.datatechnotes.com/2018/12/rnn-example-with-keras-simplernn-in.html, Note: My answer is just the operations you may have to perform. The organization of your data to have the rolling sequences (steps) must still be done. In some problems that  is done by an Embedding layer. I will delete this answer because it may be misleading